# The benefits of Composite Pattern over simple inheritance

Tags: design-patterns

I am trying to figure out why composite is better than a simple inheritance.

For example, lets say we want to implement a file system.
So basically we need files and folders.
We can use the composite pattern while `File` and `Folder` classes inherit the base interface and `Folder` class holds an interface type collection.

But it looks like (to me anyway) that simple inheritance can do the same thing.
If `File` is the root class and `Folder` inherits from `File`, the `Folder` can hold collection of `File`s, end of story.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The answer depends to some degree on the language used. Which language, or set of languages are you interested in?

Comment: In some languages there is no multiple inheritance. Your suggestion deprives you of the opportunity to inherit some functionality of Folder from anything else then File.

Comment: currently I am using c# (or java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prefer composition over inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if File is the root class and Folder inherit File, the Folder can hold collection of Files

This is essentially the Composite pattern, even if you don't call it like that :-)

Except that in your variation, Folder will inherit file-specific functionality which it can't (or worse: shouldn't) use. So you end up complicating your implementation to ensure that e.g. clients can't append bytes to the "end" of your folder etc.

FYI, the sequel to the GoF book, [*Pattern Hatching*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201432935), discusses the implementation of a file system using various patterns, including Composite. Highly recommended read.

Comment: I am asking this, because I had a test in a job interview. I didn't use the composite pattern.  I did a simple inheritance because the file don't have anything to hide from the folder class. and I am sure that that's why I didn't pass, my app was working just as they ask. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Avi, in general class design it is not recommended to inherit from concrete classes; this almost always opens the door to subtle identity/comparison problems and bugs. E.g. how would you write `File.compareTo()`, taking into account that the other object to compare to can actually be a `Folder`?

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the difference between simple inheritance and composite in your example. in both cases File and Folder are not the same type.

Comment: @Avi, the difference is that in the classic Composite, the base of the hierarchy would be an interface or abstract class (let's call it Node), implemented by both Folder and File. Thus the latter would be truly distinct types, as opposed to your design, where Folder *is a* File.

Answer (score 0):

One important difference becomes apparent in your example. Inheritance is, in most languages, a compile-time mechanism. You define the relationships of classes in your source-code.

Composition is often combined with inheritance (are rather [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)). You can decide at runtime how you compose complex objects, if the parts have a polymorphic interface.

Finally, it depends on the language used. In C++, inheritance should only be used for polymorphism, and [never for code-reuse](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/smalltalk.html#faq-30.4). In languages like Python this is not true. Here you can achieve the same thing with composition and inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you Head First Design Patterns book, the first chapter named Intro to Design Patterns talks about Strategy pattern and there is a very detail example which you can find out yourself about composition and why we favor composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I Would Recommend you better u go through this pdf:-- http://userpages.umbc.edu/~tarr/dp/lectures/Composite-2pp.pdf this pdf will definately help you. Thanks.

Comment: PDF Link is broken